# Fazer requisição à API usando angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Sou novato ainda no desenvolvimento utilizando AngularJs e estou tendo problemas para acessar uma API:

```
.controller('RegulamentoCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {

    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting')
    .then(function(response) {
        alert('teste');
    }, function(err) {
        alert(err)
    });
})
```

Ao tentar acessar esse serviço, que me retorna um JSON, eu recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Error: Unexpected request: GET
>   http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting No more request expected

Comment: Tem um erro ali ou vc tá chamando um `alert` dentro do outro?

Comment: Eu preciso me comunicar a uma API externa. É claro que não será essa. Mas tenho que entender porque ele retorna esse erro. Para depois testar a minha API. Eu estou pesquisando e vendo algo sobre $httpBackend.whenGET, mas isso não é familiar para mim. Então estou fazendo alguns testes. Mas até agora nada! :/

Comment: @Rick Wolff Isso do alert eu já tinha arrumado aqui e esqueci de corrigir na pergunta tb. Mas não é esse o problema!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Em fim descobri o problemas! :)**

O problema é que estou usando o `ngMockE2E` para processar as requisições localmente (para controle de acesso).

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngMockE2E'])
```

Sendo assim, a minha requisição de API não era passada para o servidor. Para resolver o problema eu só precisei dizer para o `ngMockE2E` repassar a minha solicitação para o servidor:

```
.run(function($httpBackend){

  ...

  $httpBackend.whenGET('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').passThrough();

 // configuração básica mock
  $httpBackend.whenGET(/templates\/\w+.*/).passThrough();
 })
```

**Font da resposta:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761045/jasmine-tests-angularjs-directives-with-templateurl